# How many litres of liquid CCl4 (Density= 1.5g/cm^3 ) must be measured out to contain 1 * 10^25 Cl atoms?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Here's what I did- 
No. of atoms of Cl - 10^25
No. of molecules of CCl₄ - 1/4 * 10^25 or 25 * 10^23

No. of moles = No . of particles/ Avogadro's No.
So (n) = 25*10^23/6.02(approx) *10^23
   (n) = 4.1
Also, No. of moles = Vol of gas at NTP/ 22.4 liters
so 4.1 = x/22.4 ======= x= 91.84 litres

But the answer in my textbook is .426 liters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Um, $\ce{CCl4}$ is a liquid. Why did you take volume of a gas? Besides, you're given the density of $\ce{CCl4}$. Find the mass first, then proceed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework without sufficient input from OP

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for how many litres of **LIQUID** $\ce{CCl4}$. Note what you have done is for **GAS**. So the steps would be:

1. Find the amount of substance of $\ce{CCl4}$ required.
2. Multiply it with its molecular weight (154 g/mol).
3. Use its density to find the volume.

Hope you understood your mistake.